I have to send an Agent Notification through Directline to Dynamics 365 Customer Service Omnichannel
I have to send notifications to agents about some logic rules, like notifications,  and not-interactives messages
The Omnichannel channel is a personalized message using Directline
I have tried sending an event type activity, but it doesn´t work
I have found a doc about this subject, that is write to use event type activity to this, but, I haven´t found a way to this..
https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/blob/main/specs/botframework-activity/botframework-activity.md#event-activity
My code
var activityOpen = new Activity()
{
From = new ChannelAccount(activity.ReplyToId, "Mensagem de sistema."),
ChannelId = "directline",
ServiceUrl = directLineServiceURL,
Text = activity.Text,
Type = ActivityTypes.Event,
Name = "notification",
Id = (activityId)
};

